# How to prepare directories for a project with many languages in one Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I want to have 1 project made of PHP, Flex and MySQL. How should I prepare directories for its SVN repository?

Should the all IDEs source code paths point to the same working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your repo could look something like:

```
repository
|
|-- PHP project 1
|
|-- Flex project 1
|
|-- MySQL project 1
|
`-- project X
```

The source code path in each IDE would correspondingly point to the following directories in your working copy:

- `../working-copy/PHP project 1/`
- `../working-copy/Flex project 1/`
- `../working-copy/MySQL project 1/`

etc.

Comment: You suggest this: working directory: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\; PHP: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\PHP; Flex: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\FLEX; SQL: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\SQL ?  It doesn't look nice.

Comment: @OP: There's no other way to tell your IDEs where they should look for their files. Also, what doesn't look nice, is that your files are in `Program Files` directory, which usually doesn't contain user data and files. The better directories would, for example, be `d:\repos\working-copy1\PHP project 1`, `d:\repos\working-copy1\Flex project 1` etc.

Comment: OK. I wanted to know the way it should look like. It should be practical first of all.  I was thinking about it for a couple of days and couldn't imagine the right way. Thank you for your help. :)